# select all option A radio buttons with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, radio-button, radio-group

if option 4 stars from the top is selected ,i want all the option 4 stars from the form to get selected.if option 3 stars is selected from the top,all the 3 stars should be selected.i tried using this code but didn't work for me.

Javascript:

```
function valueChanged() {
    if(document.getElementById("four").checked == true) {
        document.getElementById("q14").checked = true;
        document.getElementById("q24").checked = true;
        document.getElementById("q34").checked = true;
        document.getElementById("q44").checked = true;
        document.getElementById("q54").checked = true;
        } 

else if(document.getElementById("three").checked == true) {
        document.getElementById("q13").checked = true;
        document.getElementById("q23").checked = true;
        document.getElementById("q33").checked = true;
        document.getElementById("q43").checked = true;
        document.getElementById("q53").checked = true;
        }

else if(document.getElementById("two").checked == true) {
        document.getElementById("q12").checked = true;
        document.getElementById("q22").checked = true;
        document.getElementById("q32").checked = true;
        document.getElementById("q42").checked = true;
        document.getElementById("q52").checked = true;
        }

else if(document.getElementById("one").checked == true) {
        document.getElementById("q11").checked = true;
        document.getElementById("q21").checked = true;
        document.getElementById("q31").checked = true;
        document.getElementById("q41").checked = true;
        document.getElementById("q51").checked = true;

    }
     else{
        return null;
    }`
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rPuvH.jpg)

HTML:

                    
                            4 stars
                            3 stars
                            2 stars
                            1 star

```
            <div class="container con">
               <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-8 col1" ><table cellpadding="13">
                        <tr><td>1.Technical Skills</td></tr>
                        <tr><td>2.Sincerity, Commitment, Regularity, and Punctuality</td></tr>
                        <tr><td>3.Ability to clarify doubts, and teaching with relevant examples</td></tr>
                        <tr><td>4.Accessibility of teachers for doubts and clarifications outside the class</td></tr>
                        <tr><td>5.Ability to command and control the class including evaluation / examination</td></tr>
                    </table>


                </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-4 col2" align="center"><table class="table1"><tr ><td id="rate-area-1">
                            <input type="radio" id="q14" name="q1" value="4" onchange="valueChanged()"/><label for="4-star" title="Very Good">4 stars</label>
                            <input type="radio" id="q13" name="q1" value="3" /><label for="3-star" title="Good">3 stars</label>
                            <input type="radio" id="q12" name="q1" value="2" /><label for="2-star" title="Satisfactory">2 stars</label>
                            <input type="radio" id="q11" name="q1" value="1" /><label for="1-star" title="Unsatisfactory">1 star</label>
                            </td></tr>
                            <tr ><td class="rate-area-2">
                            <input type="radio" id="q24" name="q2" value="4" onchange="valueChanged()" /><label for="4-star" title="Very Good">4 stars</label>
                            <input type="radio" id="q23" name="q2" value="3" /><label for="3-star" title="Good">3 stars</label>
                            <input type="radio" id="q22" name="q2" value="2" /><label for="2-star" title="Satisfactory">2 stars</label>
                            <input type="radio" id="q21" name="q2" value="1" /><label for="1-star" title="Unsatisfactory">1 star</label>
                        </td></tr>
                        <tr ><td class="rate-area">
                            <input type="radio" id="q34" name="q3" value="4" onchange="valueChanged()" /><label for="4-star" title="Very Good">4 stars</label>
                            <input type="radio" id="q33" name="q3" value="3" /><label for="3-star" title="Good">3 stars</label>
                            <input type="radio" id="q32" name="q3" value="2" /><label for="2-star" title="Satisfactory">2 stars</label>
                            <input type="radio" id="q31" name="q3" value="1" /><label for="1-star" title="Unsatisfactory">1 star</label>
                        </td></tr>
                            <tr ><td class="rate-area">
                            <input type="radio" id="q44" name="q4" value="4" onchange="valueChanged()" /><label for="4-star" title="Very Good">4 stars</label>
                            <input type="radio" id="q43" name="q4" value="3" /><label for="3-star" title="Good">3 stars</label>
                            <input type="radio" id="q42" name="q4" value="2" /><label for="2-star" title="Satisfactory">2 stars</label>
                            <input type="radio" id="q41" name="q4" value="1" /><label for="1-star" title="Unsatisfactory">1 star</label>
                        </td></tr>
                            <tr ><td class="rate-area">
                            <input type="radio" id="q54" name="q5" value="4" onchange="valueChanged()" /><label for="4-star" title="Very Good">4 stars</label>
                            <input type="radio" id="q53" name="q5" value="3" /><label for="3-star" title="Good">3 stars</label>
                            <input type="radio" id="q52" name="q5" value="2" /><label for="2-star" title="Satisfactory">2 stars</label>
                            <input type="radio" id="q51" name="q5" value="1" /><label for="1-star" title="Unsatisfactory">1 star</label>
                        </td></tr></table>
```

please help with some code im new to javascript here

Comment: Can you give a few more details about what "it didn't work for me" means? What happened? Did your function execute or not execute? Did you get an error? etc.

Comment: I also notice you have `label for="4-star" ...` with no input with an id of `4-star` (this is true for all "n-star". The `for` attribute is supposed to match another element's id property. Also, In your function, you check id `four`, `three`, etc. which are also nowhere to be found in your html

Comment: if i select option 4 stars , all the option 4 stars are selected but when i select option 3 stars from the top nothing happens

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be more elegant to use event delegation - check the clicked target's index in its container, then select all `input`s of that index inside their containers, and `check` them:

```js
const table1 = document.querySelector('.table1');
table1.addEventListener('change', (e) => {
  const { target } = e;
  const { children } = target.parentElement;
  if (!target.matches('#rate-area-1 input[type="radio"]')) return;
  // Get the index of the changed input:
  const index = Array.prototype.indexOf.call(children, target);
  const selector = 'input:nth-child(' + (index + 1) + ')'
  table1.querySelectorAll(selector)
    .forEach(input => input.checked = true);
});
```

```html
<table class="table1">
  <tr>
    <td id="rate-area-1">
      <input type="radio" id="q14" name="q1" value="4"/><label for="4-star" title="Very Good">4 stars</label>
      <input type="radio" id="q13" name="q1" value="3" /><label for="3-star" title="Good">3 stars</label>
      <input type="radio" id="q12" name="q1" value="2" /><label for="2-star" title="Satisfactory">2 stars</label>
      <input type="radio" id="q11" name="q1" value="1" /><label for="1-star" title="Unsatisfactory">1 star</label>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="rate-area-2">
      <input type="radio" id="q24" name="q2" value="4"/><label for="4-star" title="Very Good">4 stars</label>
      <input type="radio" id="q23" name="q2" value="3" /><label for="3-star" title="Good">3 stars</label>
      <input type="radio" id="q22" name="q2" value="2" /><label for="2-star" title="Satisfactory">2 stars</label>
      <input type="radio" id="q21" name="q2" value="1" /><label for="1-star" title="Unsatisfactory">1 star</label>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="rate-area">
      <input type="radio" id="q34" name="q3" value="4"/><label for="4-star" title="Very Good">4 stars</label>
      <input type="radio" id="q33" name="q3" value="3" /><label for="3-star" title="Good">3 stars</label>
      <input type="radio" id="q32" name="q3" value="2" /><label for="2-star" title="Satisfactory">2 stars</label>
      <input type="radio" id="q31" name="q3" value="1" /><label for="1-star" title="Unsatisfactory">1 star</label>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="rate-area">
      <input type="radio" id="q44" name="q4" value="4"/><label for="4-star" title="Very Good">4 stars</label>
      <input type="radio" id="q43" name="q4" value="3" /><label for="3-star" title="Good">3 stars</label>
      <input type="radio" id="q42" name="q4" value="2" /><label for="2-star" title="Satisfactory">2 stars</label>
      <input type="radio" id="q41" name="q4" value="1" /><label for="1-star" title="Unsatisfactory">1 star</label>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="rate-area">
      <input type="radio" id="q54" name="q5" value="4"/><label for="4-star" title="Very Good">4 stars</label>
      <input type="radio" id="q53" name="q5" value="3" /><label for="3-star" title="Good">3 stars</label>
      <input type="radio" id="q52" name="q5" value="2" /><label for="2-star" title="Satisfactory">2 stars</label>
      <input type="radio" id="q51" name="q5" value="1" /><label for="1-star" title="Unsatisfactory">1 star</label>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

The picture you show and the code you posted show two different things somehow. Add that top row of input elements and give them `onchange="valueChanged()"` (not all the 4-star buttons as it currently is for some reason) and it works.

```js
function valueChanged() {
    if(document.getElementById("four").checked == true) {
        document.getElementById("q14").checked = true;
        document.getElementById("q24").checked = true;
        document.getElementById("q34").checked = true;
        document.getElementById("q44").checked = true;
        document.getElementById("q54").checked = true;
        } 

else if(document.getElementById("three").checked == true) {
        document.getElementById("q13").checked = true;
        document.getElementById("q23").checked = true;
        document.getElementById("q33").checked = true;
        document.getElementById("q43").checked = true;
        document.getElementById("q53").checked = true;
        }

else if(document.getElementById("two").checked == true) {
        document.getElementById("q12").checked = true;
        document.getElementById("q22").checked = true;
        document.getElementById("q32").checked = true;
        document.getElementById("q42").checked = true;
        document.getElementById("q52").checked = true;
        }

else if(document.getElementById("one").checked == true) {
        document.getElementById("q11").checked = true;
        document.getElementById("q21").checked = true;
        document.getElementById("q31").checked = true;
        document.getElementById("q41").checked = true;
        document.getElementById("q51").checked = true;

    }
     else{
        return null;
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="col-sm-4 col2" align="center"><table class="table1"><tr ><td id="rate-area-1">
        <input type="radio" id="four" name="q1" value="4" onchange="valueChanged()"/><label for="4-star" title="Very Good">4 stars</label>
        <input type="radio" id="three" name="q1" value="3" onchange="valueChanged()"/><label for="3-star" title="Good">3 stars</label>
        <input type="radio" id="two" name="q1" value="2" onchange="valueChanged()"/><label for="2-star" title="Satisfactory">2 stars</label>
        <input type="radio" id="one" name="q1" value="1" onchange="valueChanged()"/><label for="1-star" title="Unsatisfactory">1 star</label>
        </td></tr>

<div class="container con">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-sm-8 col1" ><table cellpadding="13">
    <tr><td>1.Technical Skills</td></tr>
    <tr><td>2.Sincerity, Commitment, Regularity, and Punctuality</td></tr>
    <tr><td>3.Ability to clarify doubts, and teaching with relevant examples</td></tr>
    <tr><td>4.Accessibility of teachers for doubts and clarifications outside the class</td></tr>
    <tr><td>5.Ability to command and control the class including evaluation / examination</td></tr>
</table>


</div>
<div class="col-sm-4 col2" align="center"><table class="table1"><tr ><td id="rate-area-1">
        <input type="radio" id="q14" name="q1" value="4" /><label for="4-star" title="Very Good">4 stars</label>
        <input type="radio" id="q13" name="q1" value="3" /><label for="3-star" title="Good">3 stars</label>
        <input type="radio" id="q12" name="q1" value="2" /><label for="2-star" title="Satisfactory">2 stars</label>
        <input type="radio" id="q11" name="q1" value="1" /><label for="1-star" title="Unsatisfactory">1 star</label>
        </td></tr>
        <tr ><td class="rate-area-2">
        <input type="radio" id="q24" name="q2" value="4" /><label for="4-star" title="Very Good">4 stars</label>
        <input type="radio" id="q23" name="q2" value="3" /><label for="3-star" title="Good">3 stars</label>
        <input type="radio" id="q22" name="q2" value="2" /><label for="2-star" title="Satisfactory">2 stars</label>
        <input type="radio" id="q21" name="q2" value="1" /><label for="1-star" title="Unsatisfactory">1 star</label>
    </td></tr>
    <tr ><td class="rate-area">
        <input type="radio" id="q34" name="q3" value="4" /><label for="4-star" title="Very Good">4 stars</label>
        <input type="radio" id="q33" name="q3" value="3" /><label for="3-star" title="Good">3 stars</label>
        <input type="radio" id="q32" name="q3" value="2" /><label for="2-star" title="Satisfactory">2 stars</label>
        <input type="radio" id="q31" name="q3" value="1" /><label for="1-star" title="Unsatisfactory">1 star</label>
    </td></tr>
        <tr ><td class="rate-area">
        <input type="radio" id="q44" name="q4" value="4" /><label for="4-star" title="Very Good">4 stars</label>
        <input type="radio" id="q43" name="q4" value="3" /><label for="3-star" title="Good">3 stars</label>
        <input type="radio" id="q42" name="q4" value="2" /><label for="2-star" title="Satisfactory">2 stars</label>
        <input type="radio" id="q41" name="q4" value="1" /><label for="1-star" title="Unsatisfactory">1 star</label>
    </td></tr>
        <tr ><td class="rate-area">
        <input type="radio" id="q54" name="q5" value="4" /><label for="4-star" title="Very Good">4 stars</label>
        <input type="radio" id="q53" name="q5" value="3" /><label for="3-star" title="Good">3 stars</label>
        <input type="radio" id="q52" name="q5" value="2" /><label for="2-star" title="Satisfactory">2 stars</label>
        <input type="radio" id="q51" name="q5" value="1" /><label for="1-star" title="Unsatisfactory">1 star</label>
    </td></tr></table>
```

---

With that said, you might wanna consider simplifying your code. Give each x-star rating a class, let the top radio-button know which radios it's connected to, and you won't have to write a giant `if-else` statement.

Comment: The top set of radio buttons doesn't stay selected, I don't know whether OP cares about that or not, but it's something to consider.